# jQuery Date and timepicker - doesn't seems to work

Tags: jquery

I try to implement a Time and a Datepicker. If I do it this way:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    /*date_obj = new Date();
    date_obj_hours = date_obj.getHours();
    date_obj_mins = date_obj.getMinutes();
    date_obj_time = " '"+date_obj_hours+":"+date_obj_mins+"'";*/

    $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "no" ] );
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: $.datepicker.W3C});  // + date_obj_time
    <!--$('#datepicker').datetimepicker();-->


});
</script>
```

The Datepicker works, but if I do it this way:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    /*date_obj = new Date();
    date_obj_hours = date_obj.getHours();
    date_obj_mins = date_obj.getMinutes();
    date_obj_time = " '"+date_obj_hours+":"+date_obj_mins+"'";*/

    <!--$.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "no" ] );-->
    <!--$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: $.datepicker.W3C});  // +date_obj_time-->
    $('#datepicker').datetimepicker();


});
</script>
```

Nothing shows up in the textfield, when I click it. How can I do this? Thanks

For the record, I followed this: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: not sure what you mean it doesnt work, I used the same code, and it works in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robasta/8MchY/

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery to php date time UI calendar

<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />
          <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" name="example1" id="example1" value="" />
          <input type="text" name="example1" id="example2" value="" />

<script>
$('#example1').datetimepicker();

$('#example2').datetimepicker();
</script>
```

You can get all css from jquery website

And here is the sample zip file i have 
http://www.woofiles.com/dl-294002-m4UvKkLO-testdate.rar